# Gnupg: Breaks software-properties-common (<= 0.96.24.3) but 0.96.20.7 is to be installed

Tags: 14.04, gnupg, vagrant

I am new to ubuntu i am trying to install vagrant but i am getting following error:

```
gp@ubuntu:~/Downloads/gnupg-2.2.13$ sudo apt install vagrant
[sudo] password for gp: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnupg : Breaks: software-properties-common (<= 0.96.24.3) but 0.96.20.7 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages
```

Comment: Looks like you have been doing something weird with `gnupg`... What's the output of `apt-cache policy gnupg`?

Comment: gnupg:
  Installed: 1.4.20-1ubuntu3.1
  Candidate: 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
     2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.2.4-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.4.20-1ubuntu3.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: Yup, you have a `gnupg` package from 16.04, but you are running 18.04. Why is this package not upgraded?

Comment: Looks like you have unwisely added a wrong-version source which provides packages that are incompatible with your release of Ubuntu. Remove all packages you installed from that unwise source, then delete that source.

Comment: @fkraiem I am not sure why this has  happened but what to do now? I am trying to upgrade it but i am getting following error:                                             E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/                                                                                                  so what to do now?

Comment: @gaurav This is a very common error; have you Googled it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a failed `apt-get dist-upgrade`. `apt-get upgrade` would just silently fail, but state that many packages weren't upgraded.

I upgraded `gnupg` individually and all was sorted out after that:

```
sudo apt install --only-upgrade gnupg
```